# Symfony2/Twig: How to set allowed Values to dropDownField

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have 3 Entities: `User` , `Report` and `ReportCategory`.
A User can put Reports in ONE ReportCategory. In the User-Entity there is a list, which ReportCategories are allowed for the user. This works all fine - I made it with a connectionTable which has the userID and the reportCategoryId.

Now I make an Array in Controller to get all ReportCategories of the current logged in User:

```
public function newAction()
    {
        $entity = new Report();
        $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

        $userId = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getId();
        $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:User')->find($userId);
        $userReportCategories = array();

        foreach($user->getReportCategories() as $reportCategory)
        {
            $userReportCategories[] = $reportCategory->getId();
        }

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
            'userReportCategories' => $userReportCategories
        );
    }
```

How can I set only these Values to my twig template field? When I make an own field it is not managed form Doctrine!

```
{{ form_row(form.reportCategory, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}, 'label': 'Category'}) }}
```

THANKS FOR ANY HELP!!!

UPDATE:
My ReportType looks like this:

```
class ReportType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('reportCategory')
            ->add('creationDate', 'date', array(
                'data' => new \DateTime()
            ))
            ->add('headline')
            ->add('text')
            ->add('user')

        ;
    }
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a form class and add an event listener so that the form is aware of the user.  The following is an adaptation of [How to dynamically Generate Forms Based on user Data](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-user-data) in the Symfony docs.  [It is not guaranteed to accurately capture your needs].

#### form class

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
// ...

class ReportFormType extends AbstractType
{
    private $securityContext;

    public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {


        // grab the user, do a quick sanity check that one exists
        $user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
        if (!$user) {
            throw new \LogicException(
                'The ReportFormType cannot be used without an authenticated user!'
            );
        }

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($user) {
                $form = $event->getForm();

                $formOptions = array(
                    'class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\ReportCategory',
                    'property' => 'category',
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {
                        // build a custom query
                        // return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                        ->select('category')
                        ->where('user = $user);
                    },
                );

                // create the field, this is similar the $builder->add()
                // field name, field type, data, options
                $form->add('userReportCategories', 'entity', $formOptions);
            }
        );
    }

    // ...
}
```

#### new action

```
public function newAction()
    {
        $entity = new Report();
        $form   = $this->createForm(new ReportFormType(), $entity);

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }
```

Comment: But how should I do my Select statement? In my connectionTable "users_reportCategories" is the User_id and the CategoryID and in my User Entity there is an ArrayCollection of the allwoed Categories. Is this possible? Because in my User-Entity Table there is NO category field.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a ManyToMany between User & ReportCategory. Presumably the connection table is not defined in `.../Entity`. Doctrine will make the connection if the entities are properly configured.  What happens when you try to select categories `->where(user = $user)`?

Comment: Thats right, there is no Entity for "users_reportCategories". Its managed by doctrine. Bute in my User Entity it looks like this: /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ReportCategory", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_reportCategories")
     **/
    private $reportCategories;

Comment: What happens when a form class with the event subscriber is used?